# where to put this "no-cache, must-revalidate" in the server code?

Tags: node.js

So when i logout from my webpage, when i click "back" from the browser, it should not display the previous page with data, it should go back to login page.

As part of the soultion, i'm using "no-cache, must-revalidate" in the header, and i have to put in the very begining of the server.js (before express, bodyParser(), session() etc.) If i move "no-cache, must-revalidate" after these app.use(bodyParser()), the "back" key will display old valid data which is really bad.

Why is this please ?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.user) {
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    }
    next();
});

// access js files in the client side
app.use(express.static('../client/', {index: 'first.html'} ));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'my test cookie', 
                  cookie:{maxAge:600000, info5:11}, // set session expires in 10 mins
                  store: new SQLiteStore 
 }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {passReqToCallback: true},
    function(req, username, password, done, next)
{
    ...
}
```